How do I enable prefix routing with Ngrok Ingress Controller for Kubernetes?
I am trying to route traffic to my application hosted in a Kubernetes cluster. At the present moment, I am using Ngroks free domains. For example happy-frog-dancing.ngrok-free.app.
I have set up this ingress-depl
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ngrok-ingress-depl
  namespace: theblock
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: ngrok
spec:
  ingressClassName: ngrok
  rules:
    - host: dominant-hawk-factual.ngrok-free.app
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: app-service
                port:
                  number: 8000
    - host: server.dominant-hawk-factual.ngrok-free.app
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: server-service
                port:
                  number: 3000


And I get an invalid error
{"level":"info","ts":"2024-07-14T14:47:56Z","logger":"controllers.ingress","msg":"Ingress is not valid so skipping it","ingress":{"name":"ngrok-ingress-depl","namespace":"theblock"}}

But it works fine when I do something like this.
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ngrok-ingress-depl
  namespace: theblock
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: ngrok
spec:
  ingressClassName: ngrok
  rules:
    - host: dominant-hawk-factual.ngrok-free.app
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: app-service
                port:
                  number: 8000
    # - host: dominant-hawk-factual.ngrok-free.app
    #   http:
    #     paths:
          - path: /server
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: server-service
                port:
                  number: 3000


What are best practices when trying to do something like this?
I have tried creating selectors in the Ngrok Dashboard but I am not familiar or well versed in how these systems work.

Thanks for using ngrok and for asking the question. The free account only supports one static domain, which includes adding prefixes. To use multiple static domains, including adding prefixes, you would need to use a paid account. You can find the options on ngrok's pricing page. Hope that helps!
